# summation sign of y in a conditional probability proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, summation

As shown in the image below, how does A turn into B?
What is the intuitive logic behind the disappearance of sigma y?
Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: You've "summed out" all dependence on $y$, essentially.  Try looking at a specific example.

Comment: This is exactly correct. Formally this is called the Law of Total Probability.

Answer (score 1):

The event $\{X=x\}$ is the union of the mutually exclusive events $\{X=x,\ Y=y\}$ for all $y$.